# How to send FCM push notification to multiple devices using google apis?

Tags: node.js, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-messaging, google-api-client

I want to send push notification to multiple devices at once. Can i pass array of tokens? 
Is it possible to do using google api? Please help me with this.

```
request(
  {
    method: 'POST',
    uri:
      'https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/projectId/messages:send',
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      'apns-priority': 'high',
      content_available: true
    },
    body: {
      message: {
        token: token,
        notification: {
          body: 'This is an FCM notification message!',
          title: 'FCM Title'
        },
        android: {
          notification: {
            sound: 'default'
          }
        }
      }
    },
    json: true
  },
  async function(error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
    console.log(body);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make the POST requests by yourself, you can prefer to:

1) Use the legacy HTTP server protocol. With that you will be able to use the "registration_ids" field which expects an array of token strings in POST body. [Docs here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref).

2) Stick to HTTP v1 API that you're using right now, but since "token" field is expecting only string, you can first subscribe your users to a specific topic and use that topic in "topic" field in POST body.

Additionally, you may prefer to use **Admin SDK** to send batch notifications. You can check for further [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send_messages_to_multiple_devices).